# File Upload using angular 5 in asp.net core 2.0. File is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I, am trying to upload the file using angular 5 in asp.net core 2.0.

Here is my server side code.

```
 public class QuestionViewModel
    {
        public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
        public FormFile FileUpload { get; set; }
    }
```

Here us the controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult QuestionPhotoPost([FromBody] QuestionViewModel model)
        {
            GenericResponseObject<List<QuestionViewModel>> genericResponseObject = new GenericResponseObject<List<QuestionViewModel>>();
            genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
            genericResponseObject.Message = ConstaintStingValue.TagConnectionFailed;
            List<QuestionViewModel> questionViewModel = new List<QuestionViewModel>();
            return Json(genericResponseObject);
        }
```

Type Script class

```
export class Data {
    QuestionText: string = "";
    FileUpload: File;
}
```

Here is the http call. The call is invoke to the controller method .

```
public QuestionPostHttpCall(_loginVM: QuestionVmData): Observable<QuestionPhotoViewModel> {
        console.log(_loginVM)
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this._httpClientModule.post<QuestionPhotoViewModel>(this.questionPhoto, _loginVM, { headers});
    }
```

Here is the data before sending to the server.

[image: picture sending the data]

But in the controller the file is value in null.

[image: null value in the file interface]

The other property are binded to the controller parameter only file is not binded.

Can anyone please tell me where I, am doing wrong.
 references - [ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Angular 4.3 File Upload with progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206643/asp-net-core-2-0-and-angular-4-3-file-upload-with-progress)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send file like multipart/form-data.

```
upload(file: File, questionText: string): Observable<FileResponseModel> {
  const url: string = Urls.uploadFiles();

  const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('attachment', file, file.name);
   formData.append('questionText', questionText);

  const options = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders().set('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
  };

  return this.httpService.post(url, formData, options);
}
```

Comment: Try to use IFormFile interface on server side. [Example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)